# how to prevent matInput inside a matFormField to truncate mutiple spaces in placeHolder

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, placeholder, mat-input

I have an angular 11 app.

i use `mat-autocomplete` and a `mat-input` behind it to show autocomplete hints in the input itself.

i use the `placeholder` property to show autocomplete data. the problem is that if i have a `matInput` inside a `<mat-form-field>` it truncates several spaces to one space. so if my placeholder holdes `foo     bar` it will show it as `foo bar`. is ther a way to overcome this ?

I created a stackblitz that represents my problem:

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wzkehx?file=src/app/app.component.html)

thank you!

Comment: Try using &emsp; between text like this `foo&emsp;bar` it will add 4 space between text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the spaces with a `&nbsp;` non-breaking space.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;moshe">
</mat-form-field>
```

[Fork of your Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sbvabx).